# Project switching in emacs

Tags: emacs, project

I would like to associate sets of buffers/files in emacs with different projects, and switch from one to other. This would involve closing all the buffers associated with the present project and open the files corresponding to the switched-to-project. I tried setting up desktops using bookmarks+ as suggested in https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/315/using-desktop-for-basic-project-management but all buffers remain open. I also tried setting up workgroups using workgroups2 (https://github.com/pashinin/workgroups2), but had similar issues. Is there an existing emacs package that could be used for this?

Comment: Here is a link to related thread -- **Is there a good Emacs project management somewhere?**:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/978984/is-there-a-good-emacs-project-management-somewhere

Comment: The thrust of that question seemed to be creating executables without using makefiles, but the answers were more general. I did try bookmarks+ and its system of tagging files and having a bookmark-file of file bookmarks seems closest to what I am looking for, but I am still working through the extensive documentation and emacswiki has been inaccessible for a few days.

Comment: FWIW, running a separate Emacs instance per project is pretty easy to manage, if you're looking for total separation between projects.

Answer (score 4):

There is an excellent package called [Projectile](https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile) that does exactly what you describe and more.

Comment: Projectile is a nice package, but it seems to be project-root-directory based and while you can have it ignore subdirectories or even file extensions it does not seem geared towards defining a project based on a set of files that may be spread between different directories.

Comment: You may want to have a look at [Perspective](https://github.com/nex3/perspective-el) in conjunction or as an alternative to Projectile.

Answer (score 2):

### Alternative suggestion

I recommend that you don't look to emacs to manage buffers, frames, and editor state separately across projects.

Instead, use a **desktop manager** and create separate desktops for each project.   This works well because not only can you have **separate emacs instances** (that you can be sure are truly separated), but you can also have separate web browsers open to documentation or **other project-specific applications** that collectively get swapped in and out when you switch between projects.

Comment: This is close to what I would like to do. However, I work on projects from work and at home, and the setup would have to be redone on changing locations (I am hesitant to depend on auto-revert mode) or when emacs is restarted.

Comment: My needs may differ from yours, but when I change or reboot machines, I do not attempt to preserve *task* state across the transition.  Those transitions are infrequent enough that I restart task state (and sync true *project* state from Github).   Unfortunately, I do at times need to immediately swap between projects, and there separate desktops running separate emacs, web browser, etc instances works well.

Answer (score 2):

You say, "*I tried setting up desktops using bookmarks+ as suggested in [using-desktop-for-basic-project-management](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/315/using-desktop-for-basic-project-management) but all buffers remain open.*".

I guess you mean that switching to a desktop does not kill buffers that existed before the switch.  Not by itself, it doesn't.  How can it guess which such pre-existing buffers you want killed?

Clearly you do not want to kill *all* buffers that existed prior to the desktop switch.

To get the behavior it seems you want, you would need to somehow decide, and specify, which such buffers you would like killed.  You could, for example, choose to kill all that have a certain mode (perhaps using `desktop-buffer-mode-handlers`).

With [**Bookmark+**](http://emacswiki.org/BookmarkPlus) you can have bookmarks that do more than one thing. In particular, here, you could create a *sequence* bookmark that chains together (1) a *function* bookmark that kills all of the buffers you want to kill and (2) a *desktop* bookmark.

Or you can perhaps make use of `desktop-after-read-hook` or `desktop-buffer-mode-handlers` to do some cleanup.

(But it sounds like you have not really thought through exactly what behavior you want with respect to buffers that you do not want to "remain open", so that you can specify it clearly.  If you can specify it then you can probably implement it fairly easily, using either desktop hooks or bookmarks or both.  Just a guess.)

Comment: In switching from one desktop (project) to the other, I would like all buffers associated with the current desktop to be killed before switching. I have now a function that kills all user-created buffers before switching. Bookmark+ seems capable of project management and a lot more such as tagging and annotating files, but the documentation is daunting for the unitiated: e.g. the doc string for bmkp-set-sequence-bookmark states "BOOKMARK-NAMES is generally a list of bookmarks or bookmark names (strings)."  and then later that they can be keyboard macros or functions.

Comment: To follow up on the previous comment: I was not clear on the specific differences between bookmarks and bookmark names and if the keyboard macros and functions would have first to be saved to a file and then bookmarks set for each of them. I would have asked for clarifications on the emacswiki page but I think comments are disabled for now.

Comment: (Yes, Emacs Wiki is still undergoing some maintenance issues.) Please read the `bmkp-set-sequence-bookmark` doc string again. The first part provides an overview. The descriptions of `BOOKMARK-NAMES` include details about a special feature: alternatives for entries in that list. "**If** [an entry is] **a function or keyboard macro, then a function bookmark is created for it** [automatically] **and that bookmark is included in the sequence.**" (That bookmark is created *automatically*.) You can follow up with me by email, if you like.

Comment: Wrt your first comment: There is not necessarily any "current desktop" that has previously been used, so "all buffers associated" with that is not defined. But if you have a function that kills the buffers you want to kill then it is simple to chain together a function bookmark that does that with a bookmark that switches to a desktop. Together they will make up a sequence bookmark.